# Drupal 8 - Can't update content

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Using Drupal 8, I've created a custom content type. After creating a piece of content with this, I've gone ahead and tried to update that piece of content. After previewing and then subsequently telling it to 'update and publish' - the content does not appear to update.

I've cleared the site's cache and checked the log, and there appear to be no signs it's actually trying to update the content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So - I'm not sure WHY this was happening, but I deleted the existing content, content type and then recreated it and it seems to work now.